# Best way to filter using awk or grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file that has the following content format;

```
1234567890 -> 
2345678901 -> /some/directory/some_file.txt
```

What I am attempting to do is to run either a grep or awk command that will only give me the lines that contain the file paths and not just the number -> combo. My present attempt to do this is;

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]+\/data\/.*/gm' file_to_test.txt
```

except it is returning all the lines. I feel like the solution is really simple and I am just not seeing it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `grep / file_to_test.txt`?

Comment: Your regex looks to be written with the intent that it search for `data` but `some/directory` doesn't contain `data`. Be sure your examples match up with each other -- you should anonymize your sample data exactly the same way you do your sample code, and test them against each other.

Comment: Why not look for a slash?

Comment: @Cyrus - This has to be the worst "DUH" moment ever for me! Using a grep -i '\/' worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use a backslash?

Comment: Because a forward slash is seen as a regex opening/closing delimiter. So, I just escaped it to be used as a literal.

Comment: Everything you added to my code is useless (backslash and `-i`).

Comment: @Skittles a forward slash is literal in a regexp. Some **tools** such as sed and, in some contexts, awk use a forward slash to delimit a regexp but grep isn't one of those tools. `-i` is to ignore upper/lower case - `/` has no different upper or lower case.

Comment: @Skittles : it's printing all lines cuz it's trying to string concat an undefined variable named `gm`, with the regex outcome, so even if the regex fails, it's concat-ting numeric zero (`0`) to empty string (`""`), forcing it to become a "string zero" ( `"0"`), which actually evaluates to **TRUE** for the pattern since it's non-empty

Comment: Can you ever have input like `2345678901 -> some_file.txt`? If so then obviously grep-ing for `/` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'NF==3 {print $0}' file_to_test.txt
```

For any line that has three fields (`NF==3`), print the whole line (`print $0`).

As *markp-fuso* pointed out: the default behaviour of awk is to just print the whole line, so the above can be shortened to just:

```
awk 'NF==3' file_to_test.txt
```

Comment: or just ` awk 'NF==3'`

Comment: I suggest to use `NF>2` to catch filenames with spaces or tabs.

Comment: you don't even need the quotes `awk NF==3 file` would do.

Comment: This is starting to sound like it belongs on [codegolf.se]. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the file pathes always contain a `/` (you did not specify this explicitly, but your example suggests that this is the case), a simple

```
grep -F / | cut -w -f 3-
```

should do. The `grep` selects the lines, and the `cut` selects the file pathes from the line. `-w` specifies that the fields in the line are separated by white space. I use `3-`, i.e. everything from field 3 to the end, to allow file pathes to contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed` to delete lines that only contain the digits and the arrow.

```
sed -e '/[0-9]* -> *$/d' ./some_file.txt
```

Output:

```
2345678901 -> /some/directory/some_file.csv
```

Comment: They want the entire line if it contains both the numbers and the file path, not just extract the file path.

Comment: @giusti I see, I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '1234567890 -> 
      2345678901 -> /some/directory/some_file.txt' |
```

---

```
mawk 'NF *= _ < $NF' FS='^[^/]+' OFS=
```

---

```
/some/directory/some_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> solution is really simple

If this is desired I would harness GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt`

```
1234567890 -> 
2345678901 -> /some/directory/some_file.txt
```

then

```
awk '$3' file.txt
```

gives output

```
2345678901 -> /some/directory/some_file.txt
```

Explanation: treat lines as containing columns separated by one-or-more whitespace characters (this is GNU `AWK` default) and find elements where 3rd column is truthy. Observe that using GNU `AWK` you might reference fields which are outside range for lines, **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes path never starts with just `0` digits, if this is not case do not use it

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*